# nicEdit font size and font family don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nicedit

I am using nicEdit as a text editor on my website. and I am including this:

All buttons work except font size and font family, the selected text doesn't change to the font size and font family I select. 
What's wrong?

Comment: post your code.. How can we know what is the error without seeing the code?

Answer (score 0):

May I see your code (css, and javascript) ?

Check if your font-family is compatible on your current Machine's OS.
There are some instances where a font-family that works fine in Windows 8 but doesn't work in Windows 7

In your CSS, you can try this:

```
.text {
        font-family:'Lucida Handwriting', 'Segoe Script', 'Monotype Corsiva';
        /* Where if the first font family is not available, the browser will use the second one, and if the second one is not also available, it will finally use the last one */
    }
```